# R: How to separate character output in a loop?

Tags: r, loops, character, separator

I'm blanking on the best way to paste a list of strings together to go into an SQL statement...  I'm having trouble with the separator bar | printing at the beginning when I don't want it to:

```
foo = "blah"
paste_all_together = NULL
for (n in 1:4) {
    paste_together =     paste(foo ,sep = "")
    paste_all_together = paste(paste_all_together, paste_together, sep = "|")
    }

> paste_all_together
[1] "|blah|blah|blah|blah"
```

I just want it to print out "blah|blah|blah|blah".   Do I need a nested loop, or is there a better itterator in R for doing this?  Or perhaps a better way to input SQL statements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps use the `collapse` option:

```
foo = list('bee','bar','baz')
paste(foo,collapse='|')
```

yields

```
"bee|bar|baz"
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is actually the first time you call `paste(paste_all_together,...)` - it essentially pastes the empty string to `"blah"`, putting a `|` between them.

There are already 2 answers here that are better than what I'm about to suggest, but to fix your example with minimal surgery would look something like this:

```
foo <- "blah"
all_together <- character(0)
for (n in 1:4) {
    all_together <- c(all_together, foo)
}
paste(all_together, collapse="|")
```

Comment: actually, it gives the same result with or without the NULL, what made the difference is the placement of the paste function outside the for loop.  Tks.

Comment: Thanks John - I actually realized that while I was posting but I forgot to change my first paragraph. =)  Changing now.

Answer (score 1):

```
paste(rep(foo,4),collapse='|')

[1] "blah|blah|blah|blah"
```

Comment: Thanks, but the strings were different, so ~unutbu's answer fits best

Comment: @John Your question and sample code suggests that strings are the same. Next time you could give all information in question.